# How to prevent AJAX post to send data if there is any validation error in form?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I am trying to submit data using Jquery AJAX (using the following script) and it is working alright but the problem is it submits data even though there are some validation errors in my forms. I am using jQuery validation plug-in 1.7 to validate my forms.

So my question is there any way to prevent the AJAX post to send data if there is any validation error in my form?

Thanks :)

```
 <script  type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){ // added
 $('#submit_item').click(function(){

   var teacherid = $('#teacherid').val();  
  var salary_amount = $('#salary_amount').val(); 



 $.ajax({

  type: "POST",
  url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>addteacher_salary/add_ajax",
  data: "teacherid="+teacherid+ "&salary_amount="+ salary_amount,
  success: function(html){
  $("#show").html(html);


   }
 });

 return false
 });
 }); // added
 </script>
```

Comment: can you add a link to the validation script your using ?

Comment: The code above has no call to any validation.

Comment: Never, ever use return false; in jQuery unless you're trying to stop immediate propagation of the event AND prevent its default behavior. Use event.preventDefault() instead, if you're just trying to prevent the default action on an event: http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/

Comment: Not sure which exact plugin you are using but any sort of validation script should be returning a boolean to signal that there are any errors.  Use the returned boolean in an if statement to control when the execution of your ajax is fired.

Comment: @ManseUK . Hi  ManseUK... here is the link to the validation script I am using... thanks :)  http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.7/jquery.validate.min.js

Comment: @Jrod  I am using this plugin.. http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.7/jquery.validate.min.js    . Would you please give me an example of how to implement what you said?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works fine: (**EDITED**)

HTML:

```
<form action="index.html" id="myForm" method="post">
<span>Salary: </span>
<input type="text" id="salary_amount" class="required" />
<input type="submit" id="submit_item" Value="Submit" />
</form>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $("#submit_item").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
     if($("#myForm").validate().form())
    {
        alert('DO AJAX POST');
    }
    else
    {
        alert('INVALID DATA');
    }
  });//submit--click
});//ready
```

Try it:  http://jsfiddle.net/jlrvpuma/ksbpY/2/

Comment: Thanks jlrvpuma. I tried your script but still no luck.. The page only reloads. Thanks for your effort man..:)

Comment: really my logic was wrong. This example works fine:   http://jsfiddle.net/jlrvpuma/ksbpY/

Comment: many Many thanks again jlrvpuma. Your logic is appositely correct.. but the problem is I have not written my form validation by myself; I am using jquery validation plugin. So the jquery plugin that I am using is doing the same job that the function IsValidData() is doing in your script... validating the form... SO now since I am using the jquery validation plugin is there any way to check if the form is validated ? Thanks :) I am using jQuery validation plug-in 1.9

Comment: Aaahhh, xD, then you must change 'if(IsValidData())' by 'if($("#myForm").validate().form())'. I've edited my previous answer.

Comment: It is the best answer for JQuery Validate Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

```
 <script  type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){ // added

    $('#myForm').validate();

     $('#submit_item').click(function(){

        var teacherid = $('#teacherid').val();  
        var salary_amount = $('#salary_amount').val(); 


        if($('#myForm').valid()) {  
             $.ajax({

              type: "POST",
              url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>addteacher_salary/add_ajax",
              data: "teacherid="+teacherid+ "&salary_amount="+ salary_amount,
              success: function(html){
              $("#show").html(html);


               }
             });
        }

        return false
     });
 }); // added
 </script>
```

Switch out #myForm for the ID of your form.  I haven't tested this but it should be enough to get you going in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks Jrod for your reply. I tried your code but this time the page only reloads without submitting any data as my forms action=""